# Flask through IIS is going to sleep

Tags: python, iis, flask

I have a Flask API being served through IIS.

At the beginning of the code (actually on `@app.before_first_request`) it loads some files that uses on runtime. It takes around 30 seconds to load everything.

The issue that I'm facing now, is that if I don't call the API for ~20mins it seems that it goes to sleep, because a call that usually takes 300ms, in that case takes ~30s which is not acceptable. After that long request, it start working fast again.

So far, I've tried disabling the idle time-out of IIS and the recycling time-out.

How can I force IIS (or Flask) to keep serving at all times?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2017 Python on IIS is deprecated as part of Python for App Service on Windows. You should switch to Linux as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up some monitoring service like [uptime robot](https://uptimerobot.com/) to ping your API periodically, I think it allows every 5 min. It will prevent app pool from getting shutdown in case of user inactivity.

Comment: I'm doing something like that. Pinging in less than 20min intervals (that's the actual timeout) but it's not very scalable nor elegant. Also, it's not accessible from the internet, so I cannot use a service like the one you suggested.